# Copying an automatically created tab to another google sheet file

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in the Google sheets on two files.

- The first one is the output from a database and it's automatically refreshed every hour. When it's refreshed, it's saved as a separate tab named with the timestamp. The previous tab (the one with the data from the previous refresh) is deleted.
- The second one contains some calculations based on the data from the first file. I copy the data from the first file to the second one, because I can't modify the data in the first one. Currently it's done manually by me.

My question is: is it possible to automate copying the data from the first file to the second one so that the second file will always have up to date data? If yes, can you please show how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this (which actually a modified version given by player0)

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url_of_sheet_or_id"; "A1:C10")
```

You mention: *"The first one is the output from a database"*
**When no sheet is defined, Google Sheets will pick up ranges from the first sheet.**

### Prerequisite

**The most recent sheet must be the first one (far left).**

*If it isn't, you should "direct" your database to place the most recently created sheet as the very first one (or use a script).*

Answer (score 0):

use `IMPORTRANGE`. example:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url_of_sheet_or_id"; "sheet_name!A1:C10")
```

Comment: thanks! however, it works if the sheet name remains unchanged. In my case when a new tab is created, the name keeps changing because it contains the refresh date. Is there any solution to refer to a newly created sheet instead of referring to a fixed one?

Comment: @kicpereniek could be a dead end. formulae cant access sheet name - only script can do this. but script reading sheet name from another spreadsheet is most likely also not possible. do you have edit access to your 1st spreadsheet? you could add a script there to read she sheet name, then place the result into cell and export this value to your 2nd sheet within importrange formula. something like: `=IMPORTRANGE("URL1"; IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "sheet1!A1")&"!A1:C10")`

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access rights to the first file. However, it consists only of 1 sheet, so the solution proposed below by another user works for me. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your help on this topic.